# React Native Select Text with Checkmark

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm new to react native and i am trying to make a text selection with checkmark and select only one Text Element , do i have to use button instead ?

[like this in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VQJC.png)

React Code

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>User Role</Text>
  <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.row}>Admin</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.row}>Assistant</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Stylesheet

```
mainContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
 detailsContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
title: {
    paddingLeft: 16,
    color: '#979797',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
```

Comment: is it a list or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `TouchableOpacity` from react-native and Icon from `react-native-elements` and then do this.

```
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>User Role</Text>
        <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.rowContainer}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ adminIsChecked: true, assistantIsChecked: false });
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text style={styles.row}>Admin</Text>
              {this.state.adminIsChecked ?
                (<Icon name='check' />)
                :
                (null)
              }
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.rowContainer}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ assistantIsChecked: true, adminIsChecked: false });
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text style={styles.row}>Assistant</Text>
              {this.state.assistantIsChecked ?
                (<Icon name='check' />)
                :
                (null)
              }
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
```

The `onPress()` of Touchable items receives a trigger when they are pressed triggering the function you have been defined in.

We will have checked one item if it state is checked, making them checked when `onPress` is called and, obviously, unchecking the other one.

To use change states of the app we use `this.setState()` and to get the state `this.state`. If you are lost about state, I recommend you to read about it first [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state).

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a variable on hold the selected item from list.

```
 state = {
            selectedId: null
        }


     renderItem({ item }) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedId: item.id
                    })
                }}>
                <View style={styles.mainContainer} >
                    <Text style={styles.title}>User Role</Text>
                    <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>Admin</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.row}>Assistant</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    {
                        this.state.selectedId === item.id ? <CHECK_MARK_IMAGE /> : null
                    }
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
```

I am hoping that you are putting your react native code into one method.